# Include a workflow before script includes in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following gitlab-ci files:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - deploy

include:
  - project: "senagon.com/templates/ci/deploy-templates"
    file:
      - "workflow.yml"
  - project: "projects/deploy-templates"
    ref: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    file:
      - "deploy.yml"

deploy-staging:
  stage: deploy
  extends:
    - .staging
  script:
    - echo "Test"
```

`deploy.yml`

```
.deploy-rules:
  rules:
    - &rules_staging
      if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "staging"
      when: never      
  staging: &rules-default-staging
    - *rules_staging
    - when: on_success   

.staging:
  rules:
    !reference [.deploy-rules, staging]
```

`workflow.yml`

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "staging"
    - when: never
```

This creates a broken pipeline if I create a new branch, because `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` does not exist in the included templates project.

My idea was therefore to include a workflow which does not let the pipeline be created if its not a push to main or staging.
Writing the workflow into the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file itself works, but the include does not work, as it is too late.

Adding rules to `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - deploy

include:
  - project: "senagon.com/templates/ci/deploy-templates"
    file:
      - "workflow.yml"
  - project: "projects/deploy-templates"
    ref: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    file:
      - "deploy.yml"
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "staging"
      - when: never

deploy-staging:
  stage: deploy
  extends:
    - .staging
  script:
    - echo "Test"
```

Fails the pipeline, because `.staging` can't be found:
`deploy-staging: unknown keys in` extends `(.staging)`

Is there a solution for this problem that I can't see? The workaround is to write a workflow in every project I have, which is terrible if there are changes to it at some point.

Comment: Why use `ref: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` to begin with when including the template? It seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: It matters, because I might want to test new deploy templates on staging and leave production pipelines unharmed. As the CI configuration gets templated and used in many different projects I saw this as the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround to this problem is:

```
include:
  - project: "templates/ci/deploy-templates"
    file: "workflow.yml"
  - local: ".gitlab-task-jobs.yml"
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "staging"
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      - when: never

non-executed-job:
  script: 
    - echo "something"
  rules:
    - when: never
```

The non-executed job is to prevent the pipeline to error, because there is no job with a script, which seems to be faulty.

*workflow.yml*

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "staging"
    - when: never
```

Therefore this job is never executed. This all needs to be done, because of the setup of the included file:

*.gitlab-task-jobs.yml*

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - create

include:
  - project: "senagon.com/templates/ci/task-ci"
    ref: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    file: "instance.yml"
  
deploy-infrastructure-staging:
  variables:
    DB_HOST: XXXXXXX
    DB_PASS: XXXXXX
```

*deploy-infrastructure-staging* is defined in the included file. I can not write anything into *script*, because it would overwrite the script that comes from the include.
Without the *local include* I get the error, that jobs need a script.

This workaround is rather crude so if there are any suggestions to improve this, I am eager to hear them...